# Transpose matrix: swapping elements doesn't alter values

Tags: c++, vector

I am trying to transpose a matrix built with vectors.

Here is the transpose function I wrote:

```
void transpose(std::vector<std::vector<int>>& fill_mat) {
    for (int i = 0; i < fill_mat.size(); ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < fill_mat.size(); ++j) {
            std::swap(fill_mat[i][j], fill_mat[j][i]);
        }
    }
}
```

It doesn't seem to be doing anything: my final results are the same as the starting ones.

---

Here is my full program:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<utility>

void print_matrix(std::vector<std::vector<int>>& to_print) {
    for (int i = 0; i < to_print.size(); ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < to_print.size(); ++j) {
            std::cout << " " << to_print[i][j];
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}

void make_matrix(std::vector<std::vector<int>>& fill_mat) {
    for (int i = 0; i < fill_mat.size(); ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < fill_mat.size(); ++j) {
            fill_mat[i][j] = rand() % 15;
        }
    }
}

void transpose(std::vector<std::vector<int>>& fill_mat) {
    for (int i = 0; i < fill_mat.size(); ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < fill_mat.size(); ++j) {
            std::swap(fill_mat[i][j], fill_mat[j][i]);
        }
    }
}


int main() {
    int size = 3;
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> matrix_sample(size, std::vector<int>(size));

    make_matrix(matrix_sample);
    print_matrix(matrix_sample);

    transpose(matrix_sample);

    std::cout << "----## transpose ##-----" << std::endl;
    print_matrix(matrix_sample);
}
```

I expected to print out the transposed matrix but the input ends up being the same as the output. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: While swapping, iterate only over a strict lower or upper triangular matrix part.

Comment: I've edited a bit more than expected. If it annoys you, you can rollback to what your question was ;)

Comment: that's fine :) I don't mind

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You swap (i,j) with (j,i) twice! That's why it has no effect.

You should only work on one half of your matrix. Plus minors improvements, we get:

```
void transpose(std::vector<std::vector<int>>& fill_mat)
{
    using size_type = decltype(fill_mat)::size_type; // better use your matrix' size type
    for (size_type i = 0; i < fill_mat.size(); ++i) {
        for (size_type j = 0; j < i; ++j) {
            using std::swap; // see swap idiom
            swap(fill_mat[i][j], fill_mat[j][i]);
        }
    }
}
```